# Systemd: Issue while getting hostname with "%H" unit file parameter in Flatcar OS

Tags: systemd, coreos

I am trying to execute logspout container with the systemd unit file. Ideally logspout container should get the environment value of `SYSLOG_HOSTNAME` as EC2 instance hostname but it is getting localhost as hostname.

```
        After=systemd-hostnamed.service
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name logspout --hostname logspout \
                                --env SYSLOG_HOSTNAME=%H \
                                --env SYSLOG_TAG=latest \
                                --env INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT=1m \
                                gliderlabs/logspout:latest
```

I have also tried to run this service after `systemd-hostnamed.service` but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

wrap %H with double quotes.
%H -> "%H"
see origin doc here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a systemd unit service like below, which basically responsible to get the hostname from the ec2 metadata service.

```
systemd:
  units:
    - name: metadata.service
      contents: |
        [Unit]
        Description=EC2 metadata agent
        Requires=docker.socket
        After=docker.socket 

        [Service]
        Type=oneshot
        Environment=OUTPUT=/run/metadata/ec2
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/mkdir --parent /run/metadata
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'echo "CUSTOM_EC2_IPV4_LOCAL=$(curl\
          --silent --url http://169.254.169.254/2009-04-04/meta-data/local-ipv4\
          --retry 10)" > $${OUTPUT}'
```